# Can't load my app on the Samsung galaxy prevail

Tags: android

I just got a samsung Galaxy prevail phone and i was going to install my app on the phone. but it dosen't give me that chose. I use my brother phone the newset evo and I was able to just fine so the 
android sdk was install correct. I also did not get a plane or activation.

my qustion is do i need to download a file or  activation before i can install the app i made?

thank you

ok so I went to setting and made sure that unknow Sources is on. However it still not showing up on
the AVD manger and I guss i should tell you guys i have a pc.

Answer (score 1):

On your phone ensure the following is checked:
Settings→Applications→Unknown sources

Download and install the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) and run:

```
adb -d install "the_name_of_apk"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't signed your app then you need to enable untrusted apps.

From the home screen press the menu button then

Settings->Applications->Unknown Sources

That should allow you to install your application